In Quarkus, how to get a url to another resource
In Quarkus, when returning a url to another resource or a url for a redirect,
how to get the url of the other resource?
The path to a resource method is defined in @Path annotations. I would not want to use strings to reference to such a resource since that would then break as soon as the @Path is changed.
For testing there is @TestHTTPResouce @TestHTTPEndpoint(MyResource.class) URL myResourceUrl but there does not seem to be a similar functionality for the main code.
Using UriBuilder.fromResource(MyResource.class).build(); only returns a string with the path of the resource, but now the full url like 'https://server:port/basepath/myresource'.
Also, UriBuilder.fromMethod(MyResource.class, "someMethod") only returns the path of the method, e.g. 'someMethod', and is not prefixed with the path of the resource itself. I would expected at least a 'myResource/someMethod' path.
Jakarta's @Context ResourceContext context argument only provides a way to get an instance of MyResource but not to get the url.
The UriInfo context allows resolving of a URI, but that URI cannot be determined for a resource method.

Normally, the way it works is that you add a UriInfo method parameter, then you do something like:
package org.acme;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@Path("/api")
public class GreetingResource {


    @Path("hello")
    @GET
    public String hello() {
        return "hi";
    }
    
    @Path("uri")
    @GET
    public String uri(UriInfo uriInfo) {
        return uriInfo.getBaseUriBuilder()
         .path(GreetingResource.class)
         .path(GreetingResource.class, "hello")
         .build().toString();
    }
}


You have to add the path to the class, and to the method, if both are annotated with @Path.
